# Webpack erroring on bundling font awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome, webpack-2, css-loader, webpack-3

I'm having issues with my webpack build (v3), it's a migration from v1 however, it breaks on the importing of the font-awesome file (css) I have on my `app.js` page. This is the response from webpack:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
Module parse failed: /../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* FONT PATH
|  * -------------------------- */
| @font-face {
|   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
|   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
```

Below is my config file:

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const path = require('path');

const join = path.join;
const resolve = path.resolve;
const root = resolve(__dirname);
const src = join(root, 'src');

const chalk = require('chalk');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const precss = require('precss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const _ = require('lodash');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const dotEnvVars = dotenv.config();
const environmentEnv = dotenv.config({
  path: path.join(root, 'config', `${NODE_ENV}.config.js`),
  silent: true,
});
const envVariables = _.merge({}, dotEnvVars, environmentEnv);
const defines = Object.keys(envVariables).reduce(
  function (memo, key) {
    const val = JSON.stringify(envVariables[key]);
    memo[`__${key.toUpperCase()}__`] = val;
    return memo;
  },
  {
    __NODE_ENV__: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
    __DEBUG__: NODE_ENV === 'development',
  }
);
const webpackConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve('src/app.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist/'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  cache: true,
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    overlay: true,
    compress: true,
    lazy: true,
    stats: {
      assets: true,
      chunks: true,
      colors: true,
      modules: true,
      modulesSort: 'field',
      publicPath: true,
      version: true,
      reasons: true,
    },
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react', 'react-hmre'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', query: { sourceMap: true } }, 'postcss-loader'],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|otf)(\?v=[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9])?$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[name].[ext]' } }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf(\?\S*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000 } }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?\S*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000 } }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?\S*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: 'url-loader', options: { mimetype: 'image/svg+xml', limit: 10000 } }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?\S*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'url-loader', options: { mimetype: 'application/octet-stream', limit: 10000 } },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: { mimetype: 'application/font-woff', limit: 10000, name: './[hash].[ext]' },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000 } }],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(defines),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Privacy Dashboard',
      template: 'default.ejs',
      inject: true,
      hash: true,
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: src,
        postcss: [precss(), autoprefixer(), cssnano()],
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'app.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve('src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.css', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      css: join(src, 'styles'),
      containers: join(src, 'containers'),
      components: join(src, 'components'),
      utils: join(src, 'utils'),
      styles: join(src, 'styles'),
      demo: join(src, 'demo'),
      stores: join(src, 'stores'),
      config: join(src, 'config', env),
    },
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Comment: This isn't really a reactjs question..